# Как выровнять тайтл (смотреть пример)

Tags: css, position

Ребята, короче, такие дела уже по-моему задавал тут вопрос этот . Не могу вертикально отцентровать элемент (в хроме норм, а в IE и firefox - нет )

http://afisha.net.ru

[image: https://i.imgur.com/I0njTUV.png]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<div class="main  mx-auto mb3" style="margin-top: 135px">
 <div class="clearfix mxn1">
  <div class="md-col md-col-9 px1  ">


    <div class="relative">


<div class="my-slider">

<?php 
global $db;
$abc = $db->query("SELECT * FROM admin_panel WHERE label='slider' ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0,6 ");
while ($data = $abc->fetch_array()) 
{ ?>
    <div class="relative zoom-blurb">
    <div class="absolute table white mx-auto top-0 left-0 right-0 bottom-0 cover-text z1"><div class="table mx-auto">
     
      <p class="h1 mb1 "><?php echo $data['title'] ?></p>
      <p class=" mt0 mb0 xs-hide">Категория: <?php echo $data['category'] ?> Опубликовано <?php echo showDate($data['datetime']) ?></p>
      <p class="h3 mt1 xs-hide"><?php echo $data['slogan'] ?></p>


    </div></div>
    <a href="fullpost/<?php echo $data['id'] ?> "><img src="<?php echo $data['image']; ?>" alt=""></a>
   </div>


<?php }

 ?>

</div>
<!-- or ul.my-slider > li -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tiny-slider/2.8.2/min/tiny-slider.js"></script>
<!-- NOTE: prior to v2.2.1 tiny-slider.js need to be in <body> -->




<script>
  var slider = tns({
    container: '.my-slider',
    items: 1,
    slideBy: 'page',
    controls: true,
    nav:true,
    controlsText: ['<','>'],
    autoplay: false
  });

</script>

        



  </div>
```

PS Да, и там используются классы с фреймворка BassCSS, для упрощения стилизации; tiny-slider 2.0 github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider

Comment: Каким способом в Chrome выравниваете?

Comment: Если уже задавал такой вопрос, который был так же оформлен и не получил ответа и помощи, боюсь и сей раз ничего не измениться... Оформи вопрос надлежащим образом...

Comment: Блин, там просто там громоздкий код ( то есть внутри див див див див див див итд ) Крч нужно разместить текст внутри слайдера, но чтобы текст был блоком и внутри этого блоко выравнивание текст по левому краю было. Получилось чтобы заработало использовать таблицы ( но как видите  не везде работает )

Comment: это какой там слайдер ? и в любом случае надо видеть исходники

Comment: Написано смотреть пример, а примера в вопросе нет... Ну как так-то

Comment: tiny-slider 2.0 https://github.com/ganlanyuan/tiny-slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я увидел, продравшись сквозь тонны всякого, там для центрирования используется блочок с абсолютным позиционированием и несколькими несовместимыми свойствами. Хром умеет разбираться с таким безобразием, позволяя разработчикам косячить, прочие браузеры - еще нет.

Универсальный и красивый способ центрирования абсолютно позиционированного блока любых размеров:

```
.my_class {
  position:absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Нет - этот способ не работает внутри слайдера. - Я пробовал давно много раз.

Comment: @LyubaIvanova вы можете по человечески пояснить что требуется ?

Comment: если не работает внтури слайдера, значит, там что-то накосячено.